# Can't turn visible a Protected Sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I protected several Sheets, that are hidden, using the following code (just an example):

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="something", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Unfortunately I can't turn visible the sheets hidden and protected and I got the corresponding error '1004'. How can I solve this using VB? The code to turn visible the sheets is:

```
For I = 3 To 7

Worksheets(I).Activate
Sheets(I).Visible = xlSheetVisible

Next I
```

It is possible to make it visible without unprotect the sheets?

Comment: in your loop, unprotect the sheet, make it visible, then reprotect it.  Also, you shouldn't need to activate it to make it visible.

Comment: If the workbook is protected , unprotect the workbook (not the worksheets)

Comment: only some sheets are protected.

Comment: run this: `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure` . if you get TRUE then the workbook is protected and you have to unprotect it